# How do i allow only specific domain email to sign up on my micro blog

Tags: php, email-validation, user-registration

i want only my corporate people to sign up , who've got E.G abc@ourcompany.com emails and not other people like abc@gmail.com or abc@outlook.co etc.

i'm not able to post my code here . i've posted it here , pls check and help
http://pastebin.com/0aJZfHWx

Comment: hope they are not signing up to anything important, checking who they are based on email is not great approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
$allowed_domains = array("ourcompany.com");
$email_domain = array_pop(explode("@", $email));
if(!in_array($email_domain, $allowed_domains)) {
    // Not an authorised email 
}
```

It's simply. Make an array for allowed domains, explode by `@`, get the last element of the array and check if it exists in the allowed domains array.

Comment: can you please tell me how do i put this in this code: http://pastebin.com/0aJZfHWx
i'm a kinda noob :(

Comment: would you like your pillow fluffed also?

Comment: No, i can do that. i asked for help only for what i am not able to do. But anyways, Thank you (Y)