# PHP Institutional Email Validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, email, registration

I would like to make a user registration form which only accepts email addresses from my university.

e.g

`me@gmail.com, me@yahoo.com, me@live.com = INVALID`

`me@university.ac.uk = VALID`

what types of terms and queries should I start researching to achieve this? I am new to PHP, but from the homework, I've done so far can only find tutorials on how to validate emails based on rejecting invalid inputs, rather than only accepting valid domain extensions such as `@university.ac.uk`

Hope this makes sense, not trying to get code written for me (although visual explanations are helpful), just asking for a few pointers to help get in the right direction.

Comment: so it means you need to @university.ac.uk as fix formate right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i allow only specific domain email to sign up on my micro blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454353/how-do-i-allow-only-specific-domain-email-to-sign-up-on-my-micro-blog)

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a regular expression to check for a valid email ending in .ac.uk. Try starting with the PHP function `preg_match()` and searching for 'regular expressions' online.

Comment: Just and additional FYI: the solutions proposed here won't work on _ALL_ email addresses as they do not account for special cases (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220158/php-filter-validate-email-does-not-work-correctly); if you are sure your visitors will not use exotic email addresses, then @G4Hu's answer seems the most straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you regex for email that your requirements.

`/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@\buniversity.ac.uk/`

Please visits here https://regex101.com/r/KkJeho/9

Answer (score 0):

If you first make sure the address is an email, and then `explode()` the email, you can check if the server matches:

```
<?php
$email = "foo@university.ac.uk";
$allowed_servers = array("university.ac.uk", "other_server.maybe");
if (filter_var($email, "FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL")) {
    $check = explode("@", $email);
    if (in_array($check[1], $allowed_servers)) {
        // server checks out
    } else {
        // server doesn't check out
    }
} else {
    // invalid email address
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, requiring domain specific email addresses in a form means you need to utilize it at least server side (the mail addresses submitted needs to be checked againist non conforming user input). In simple words, if someone wants to "play" with your site he could send "bad" requests so that you store the wrong information in your database.
Moreover it's not compulsory but if you want to aid the user you can add client side verification.

As far as server side code is concerned you can use regular expressions to validate input. See [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm) and [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html)

Additionally, client side code can be used to assist the user in order to submit the form properly. You have more choices for this:

[HTML5 regex](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)
[Javascript regex](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)